# How to check and get value and show in html

Tags: php

Im unable to get value camparison

```
if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
     $indexRegValue = $_POST['RegValue']; // value from index page e.g 490
     echo '$indexRegValue';
     $ipValue = "490";
     $lfvalue = 790;
     $spvalue = 990;
     if ($ip == $indexRegValue) {
         $titlevalue = "490";
     } else if ($lfvalue === $indexRegValue) {
         $title = "790";
     } else if ($spvalue === $indexRegValue) {
         $titlevalue = "990";
     }
}
echo $titlevalue; // value to print
```

How to check and get value and show in html

Comment: $_POST['RegValue']; // value from index page e.g 490 is indexRegvalue equal to 490 or "490" ?

Comment: And did you mean `$titlevalue` instead of `$title` in the first `else if`? And why do you switch between `equals` and `identical` in the comparisons?

Comment: yeah it $titlevalue and its $ip===$indexRegValue

Comment: regvalue is coming from hidden input

Comment: <input type=hidden name="RegValue" id="RegValue" value="490">

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
    $indexRegValue = $_POST['RegValue']; // value from index page e.g 490
    echo '$indexRegValue';
    $ipValue = "490";
    $lfvalue = 790;
    $spvalue = 990;
    if ($ipValue == $indexRegValue) {      // corrected variable
       $titlevalue = "490";
                                 } 
    else if ($lfvalue == $indexRegValue) {  
     $titlevalue = "790";          // Corrected variable
                                     } 
   else if ($spvalue == $indexRegValue) {   //changes
     $titlevalue = "990";
                                     }
                           }
   echo $titlevalue; // value to print
```

There were typos in the variable which you are checking and printing

Answer (score 0):

> You have typo mistake in `$ip` instead od `$ipValue`

```
if (isset($_POST['Register'])) {
     $indexRegValue = $_POST['RegValue']; // value from index page e.g 490
     echo '$indexRegValue';
     $ipValue = "490";
     $lfvalue = 790;
     $spvalue = 990;
     if ($ipValue == $indexRegValue) {// your typo mistake
         $titlevalue = "490";
     } else if ($lfvalue == $indexRegValue) {//changes
         $titlevalue = "790";// your typo mistake
     } else if ($spvalue == $indexRegValue) {//changes
         $titlevalue = "990";
     }
}
echo $titlevalue; // value to print
```

Comment: thanks and i was comparing wrong values so that why no result was shown, thank to all